# NVDA does not read abbr title

Tags: html, wcag, wcag2.0, nvda

My HTML page contains the following line:

```
<abbr title="World Wide Web Consortium">W3C</abbr>
```

When reading the page with NVDA screen reader (version 2016.1) it only read "W3C" but never the title.

I tried to find a setting in NVDA to activate the reading of the title attribute but without any luck. Nothing also on Google about this limitation (last version of NVDA should read titles).

I have not tried with any other screen readers like JAWS or Voice Over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Blind people understand abbreviations like other people**. So they do not want to hear the definition of FBI, NASA, W3C each time those abbreviations are spoken. (although this can be configured in some screen readers)

If you think that an abbreviation should be explained, then everyone is concerned, and providing a definition with an `abbr` tag is a bad idea, because it requires a standard user to hover the term with a mouse.

In fact, the only interest of the `abbr` tag is to mark semantically an abbeviation, in order to be spell-out for instance. If you want to explain an abbreviation use full definitions.

> **Bad example**: `<abbr title="Doctor">Dr</abbr> Martin lives in Lincoln <abbr title="Drive">Dr</abbr>`
>
> `He works for the <abbr title="Worldwide Web Consortium">W3C</abbr>`
>
> **Good example:** `Doctor Martin lives in Lincoln Drive`
>
> `He works for the World Wide Web Consortium (known as the <abbr>W3C</abbr>)`

Comment: Thank you. In my particular case ("W3C" was just an example but is not my real business use case) I have to keep the abbreviation displayed only. This is a request from customer (who is controlling the design) and with the context around it can easily been understood by the non-blind user. Context can be trickier to grasp for blind user however. This is why I have to add the screen reader only help (also a request from the customer). Therefore my question was not how to avoid the use case but rather how to address it efficiently.

Comment: As long as you have an information which is not accessible to all users, this won't be accessible. People with a screen magnifier (which is more common than a screen reader) can only view a small area (let's say for instance the equivalent of 320x240 CSS pixels) but don't use a screen reader. They won't have any benefit of "screen reader only" solution and won't benefit of the context. So yes, you will answer your client request, but not people needs. But I perfectly understand that sometimes, we have to give a solution to customers even if they ask for bad things.

Answer (score -1):

I found this article that clarifies a lot:
[title attribute and accessibility](https://silktide.com/i-thought-title-text-improved-accessibility-i-was-wrong/)

Basically, using title attributes is of no use for screen reader. Instead we should always use hidden text for screen readers (in addition to the title attribute that is still useful for other cases).

For example if you use Bootstrap with the question example:

```
<abbr title="World Wide Web Consortium">
  W3C
  <span class="sr-only">World Wide Web Consortium</span>
</abbr>
```

Comment: Accessibility targets different kind of people who are not all of them blind people. Defining the abbreviations is really useful for people with cognitive disabilities, which is not the case of blind people.

Comment: This is a very bad example. Screen reader users are same people as everyone else. No-one will want to hear abbreviations like NATO or FBI (and W3C too) being read in full every time they appear in the text. At least with the `title` attribute it is possible not to read it in the screen reader settings. With this one, there is no way to block it from being read.

Comment: Yes @tomasz86 but again this is a customer requirement and it is for an abbreviation that is not as famous as W3C (W3C is just an example here).

Comment: @jthe In case of less known abbreviations why not just do `W3C (World Wide Web Consortium)`? This will benefit both blind and sighted users. In this particular example I cannot see any valid reason to expand the abbreviation only to screen reader users and hide it for everyone else. You probably could provide the full form once (in brackets) and then just use the abbreviation alone.

Comment: Moreover, **accessibility does not mean just screen readers**. Hiding important content this way resembles the old deprecated table summary attribute which in the end did not help anybody. I believe that important content should be accessible to all users, not just those with a screen reader (or any other specific group).

Comment: @tomasz86, I agree with you on the principle but I guess you have never faced a real customer before. I told you the requirement is what it is and I am not looking for a way to avoid it but rather to handle it the best I can. My customer does not want explanatory brackets, it does not fit in the design and we already have the title tooltip for non blind users anyway.

Comment: @jthe You are probably right. I am still writing this so maybe other people will see it and think again before doing something like this. Using this method to explain each abbreviation all the time is an anti-pattern. It does not help sighted users at all (because they cannot see the text) and actually makes everything more difficult to understand for the blind who are forced to hear the full form of each abbreviation over and over again every time it appears in the text. As a side note, the title tooltip in its default form is problematic (i.e. unusable) for touch screen users.

Comment: @tomasz86, I will change the selected answer so other people are redirected to the better way of doing thing. I the meantime I keep my workaround for my specific customer requirement. Thank you for the interesting discussion

Comment: @jthe It is all right. I have a strong stance in this matter as I am already annoyed enough with complete ignorance of accessibility in real life (like people parking in front of wheelchair ramps, or young and healthy people using special elevators despite the huge sign "for disabled only"... seriously?). However, I believe that accessibility should always be consulted and tested with those who are to use it. It must not be decided arbitrarily which is often the case (unfortunately).

Comment: I would just like to add one more thing on the `title` attribute and abbreviations in general. People often talk a lot about screen reader accessibility, etc. but completely forget about those who rely on the keyboard (or other alternative input devices). By default, the title text is totally inaccessible to them. Unfortunately, the majority of the "screen reader friendly" solutions have no use for them too :(